How to add svg image as icon in AnimatedBottomNavigationBar
I need to use this custom bottomNavBar but with Svg images instead of Icons.
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  body: pages[_bottomNavIndex],
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/addPost");
    },
    elevation: 10,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 30,
    ),
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
    icons: [
      Icons.home,
      Icons.shopping_bag_rounded,
      Icons.flag,
      Icons.person_rounded
    ],
    iconSize: 30,
    leftCornerRadius: 34,
    rightCornerRadius: 34,
    height: 80,
    activeIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
    gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
    notchMargin: 8,
    elevation: 30,
    notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.smoothEdge,
    onTap: (index) => setState(() => _bottomNavIndex = index),
    backgroundColor: CasaColors.white,
  ),
);


this icons
final List<SvgPicture> iconList = [
  SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/svg_icons/home.svg',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  ),
  SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/svg_icons/shopping_bag.svg',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  ),
  SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/svg_icons/flag.svg',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  ),
  SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/svg_icons/person.svg',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  ),
];


but I has an Error 'The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.'
and I can't convert svg to IconData.
Can somebody help?
I tried to convert svg to change bottomNavBar type but it can't paint shape I need.

The error is because icons is requiring List<IconData>? and you provide a List<SvgPicture>.
There is a more flexible way to build custom icons. You can use the AnimatedBottomNavigationBar.builder, and to provide a tabBuilder function that can return any widget.
AnimatedBottomNavigationBar.builder(
      itemCount: iconList.length,
      tabBuilder: (int index, bool isActive) {
        // TODO: Customize it with an active color, and adjust it with your requirements.
        return iconList[index];
      activeIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
      gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
      notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.verySmoothEdge,
      leftCornerRadius: 32,
      rightCornerRadius: 32,
      onTap: (index) => setState(() => _bottomNavIndex = index),
      //other params
   ) 

